# How do I output text or return an object from a script?

Tags: powershell

How can I make the output of a script behave similar to `Get-Process` cmdlet, where it will either return a human readable formatted output if invoked directly, or an object i.e. PSCustomObject which would be used in another script / pipeline?

Basically, the script understands its calling context.

Obviously, I can do `MyScript.ps1` (dumps formatted text) or `MyScript.ps1 -AsObject` but that doesn't seem to be conventional.

Also, if there's a term for this, please educate me.

Comment: Scripts or functions may return any "object". Generally, if a script may or not return something the parameter used is `-Passthru` to instruct the script to return objects. For a script to generate some output, the cmdlet used is generally `Write-Output`.

Comment: Yes, this does seem to be the conventional way to do this. Thanks. If you want to put that in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Also, any idea why Get-Process is 'smart' and doesnt need this flag?

Comment: Get-process always returns an array of Process objects.  This gets converted to text later, when it is to be put on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scripts or functions may return any "object". Generally, if a script may or not return something the parameter used is -Passthru to instruct the script to return objects. For a script to generate some output, the cmdlet used is generally Write-Output.

In general a `Get-*` cmdlet is about to return something that is to be used on subsequent cmdlets in the pipeline. This is not the case by example for `Set-*` which may or not return objects. That's why `-Passtru` parameter is more present  on `Set-*` so that you can continue the pipeline for any reason.